# define jQuery.ajax as a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, methods, deferred

how can I define the jQuery ajax-method as a property of my object?

I have the ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../PHP/RoadtripsTable.php",
    data: ({fnChoice: "listRoadtrips"})
})
```

and I would like to define a property x of an object o like this:

```
var o = {
    x: $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../PHP/RoadtripsTable.php",
        data: ({fnChoice: "listRoadtrips"})
    })
}
```

but this does not seem to work. I need o.x to be a deferred since I am using it inside of $.() from the jQuery-Library.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var o = {
  x: function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../PHP/RoadtripsTable.php",
      data: ({fnChoice: "listRoadtrips"})
    });
  }
}
```

This alternative declaration should also work:

```
var o = {
  x() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../PHP/RoadtripsTable.php",
      data: ({fnChoice: "listRoadtrips"})
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: no this does not work. The when clause - where I hand the method `x()` to -does not work when I write it like this. Maybe it is because the `function() {..}` wrapper does not make it a deferred anymore

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like, where you're using this method?

Comment: Don't forget to return the jqXHR from the function - `x: function() { return $.ajax(...); }`